# util date to the sql date typecasting

Tags: java, jdbc

```
java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date();

// giving error
java.sql.Date sqlDate= (java.sql.Date) utilDate;
// correct
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
```

Why I am unable typecasting the  util.date to SQL.date

Comment: Because `java.sql.Date` extends `java.util.Date`,
it's possible to cast sql date to util date only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`java.util.Date` is a parent of `java.sql.Date`. In Java parent type cannot be casted to child.

```
private static class A {

}

private static class B extends A {

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = new A();
    B b = new B();

    B ba = (B) a; // java.lang.ClassCastException
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the below solution to convert date in util to sql date:

```
{
    java.util.Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
    java.util.Date dateInUtils = new java.util.Date(); 
    calender.setTime(dateInUtils);
    calender.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calender.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calender.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calender.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);    
    java.sql.Date dateInSql = new java.sql.Date(calender.getTime().getTime()); 
    System.out.println("dateInUtils:" + dateInUtils);
    System.out.println("dateInSql:" + dateInSql);
}
```